# Getting unbound prefix on ScrollView

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, xml-parsing

I am trying to display two tables side-by-side. Originally only one table was in the ScrollView but I expanded it to all tables.  Now im getting an unbound prefix on the ScrollView. Any ideas? I didnt get the error until after encompassing it around both tables.

**EDIT** Removed second table and relative layout inside the ScrollView. No effect.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/aegis">

//Some TextViews here

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/techOvr"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/shipInfoLinearLayout1">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/headers"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            //TextViews

        </RelativeLayout>

        <ScrollView
            androud:id="@+id/tableScroll"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/headers"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp">


    <TableLayout>
            //Mess load of TableRows and TextViews.
        </TableLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved...apparently i misspelled an android: tag on the id. Should have been obvious **facepalm**!